# FlatFile library, delimited layout, wrong parsing when multiple fields are empty at the end of the row

Tags: c#

We use in some of our applications the FlatFile library (https://github.com/forcewake/FlatFile) to parse some files delimited with separator (";"), since a lot of time without problems.

We faced yesterday a problem receiving files having multiple fields empty at the end of the row.

I replicated the problem with short console application to show and permit you to verify in a simple way:

```
using FlatFile.Delimited;
using FlatFile.Delimited.Attributes;
using FlatFile.Delimited.Implementation;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace FlatFileTester
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var layout = GetLayout();
            var factory = new DelimitedFileEngineFactory();

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            using (FileStream file = new FileStream(@"D:\shared\dotnet\FlatFileTester\test.csv", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                byte[] bytes = new byte[file.Length];
                file.Read(bytes, 0, (int)file.Length);
                ms.Write(bytes, 0, (int)file.Length);
                var flatFile = factory.GetEngine(layout);
                ms.Position = 0;
                List<TestObject> records = flatFile.Read<TestObject>(ms).ToList();

                foreach(var record in records)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Id=\"{0}\" - DescriptionA=\"{1}\" - DescriptionB=\"{2}\" - DescriptionC=\"{3}\"", record.Id, record.DescriptionA, record.DescriptionB, record.DescriptionC));
                }

            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static IDelimitedLayout<TestObject> GetLayout()
        {
            IDelimitedLayout<TestObject> layout = new DelimitedLayout<TestObject>()
                .WithDelimiter(";")
                .WithQuote("\"")
                .WithMember(x => x.Id)
                .WithMember(x => x.DescriptionA)
                .WithMember(x => x.DescriptionB)
                .WithMember(x => x.DescriptionC)
                ;

            return layout;
        }
    }

    [DelimitedFile(Delimiter = ";", Quotes = "\"")]
    public class TestObject
    {
        [DelimitedField(1)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [DelimitedField(2)]
        public string DescriptionA { get; set; }

        [DelimitedField(3)]
        public string DescriptionB { get; set; }

        [DelimitedField(4)]
        public string DescriptionC { get; set; }
    }

}
```

This is an example of file:

```
1;desc1;desc1;desc1
2;desc2;desc2;desc2
3;desc3;;desc3
4;desc4;desc4;
5;desc5;;
```

So the first 4 rows are parsed as expected:

- All fields with values in the first and second row
- empty string for third field of third row
- empty string for fouth field of fourth row

in the fifth row we expect empty string on third and fourth field, like this:

```
Id=5
DescriptionA="desc5"
DescriptionB=""
DescriptionC=""
```

instead we receive this:

```
Id=5
DescriptionA="desc5"
DescriptionB=";"        // --> THE SEPARATOR!!!
DescriptionC=""
```

We can't understand if is a problem of configuration, bug of the library, or some other problem in the code...

Anyone have some similar experiences with this library, or can note some problem in the code above not linked with the library but causing the error...?

Comment: Why use a library for something so simple.  Try : string line = "";
while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
   string[] splitLine = line.split(new char[] {';'}).ToArray();
}

Comment: Someone before me, who is not anymore in the enterprise, wrote the application, now the application is in production, it's more more more more more complicated than the example above, it's only an example, so, considering the time we have to fix, change the application is not my choice, at least now...

Comment: Have you tried the nullable attribute for `DescriptionC`, or perhaps a pre-parser?

Comment: @PeterSmith, thx a lot for advice, I see on github's library an example attribute for an nullable int: [DelimitedField(3, NullValue = "=Null")], I tried some combinations based on this example, but I can't reach a success, maybe I can't understand how exactly apply it (assuming the problem is in attribute configuration and there's no other bug in the code or in the library)... anyway the code I wrote above is as simple as possible, I expected that empty string were treated as empty string, at first glance I supposed there is not the need of that attribute... but I can be on error :)

Comment: the library is probably using remove empty entries which need to be changed :   string[] splitLine = line.split(new char[] {';'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToArray(); }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look and debug the source code of the open source library: https://github.com/forcewake/FlatFile.

It seems there's a problem, in particular in this case, in witch there are 2 empty fields, at the end of a row, the bug take effects on the field before the last of the row.

I opened an issue for this libray, hoping some contributor of the library could invest some time to investigate, and, if it is so, to fix: https://github.com/forcewake/FlatFile/issues/80

For now we decided to fix the wrong values of the list, something like:

```
        string separator = ",";
        //...
        //...
        //...
        records.ForEach(x => {
            x.DescriptionC = x.DescriptionC.Replace(separator, "");
        });
```

For our case, anyway, it make not sense to have a character corresponding to the separator as value of that field...

...even if it would be better to have bug fixing of the library